# How to fix mysqli_stmt_close invalid object error?

Tags: php

I was programming my login system, but I got an error that I cannot fix:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt in C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\Login System\includes\signup.inc.php on line 61.

When I save the file and open it, everything works fine until data must be sent to the database. In that moment I get that error and the database is empty.

Here is the code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmailuid");
        exit();
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    } elseif ($password !== $passwordrepeat) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);  
        if ($resultCheck > 0){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
        exit();
        }
        else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, mailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
         if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {


         }
         else {
            $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
            exit();
            }
        }
      }


    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
else {
header("Location: ../signup.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question. Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn’t this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EdCottrell i edited it, code is now inside

Comment: That’s better, but please (1) format it so we can read it (start by lining up the braces, as in `{` and `}`) and (2) make sure this is really a *minimal* example. There seems to be a lot of unnecessary/irrelevant code here. Help us help you.

Comment: A hint: it looks like you are closing your statement in the wrong place, where you haven’t necessarily defined `$stmt` before trying to close it. Formatting your code would help a lot with spotting this kind of error.

Comment: @EdCottrell idk what you mean

Comment: @EdCottrell im sorry, but i cannot format it becouse i dont know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** You call `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` in a section of code where `$stmt` may not be set.

## The Problem

Your primary problem here is that you can't tell what code is running before you get to the `mysqli_stmt_close()`. There are two reasons for this: (1) too much code complexity and (2) bad (no) formatting.

## Fixing Your Formatting

The earlier versions of your post included code that wasn't formatted at all (it looks like you have edited it to make it *better*, but it still has some problems). Formatted properly, your code looks like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=" . $username . "&mail=" . $email);
        exit();
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmailuid");
        exit();
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=" . $username);
        exit();
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=" . $email);
        exit();
    } elseif ($password !== $passwordrepeat) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passcheck&uid=" . $username . "&mail=" . $email);
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=" . $email);
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, mailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {


                } else {
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

In the future, you should use an IDE like PHPStorm, which will help you tremendously with formatting your code and catching obvious errors like this.

## Finding the Error

For simplicity, let's just look at the structure of your code (`...` indicates code I'm leaving out here):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordrepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
        // ...
    } 
    // ... long series of elseif statements here...
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        // ...
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, `$stmt` is only set in one place, inside an `else` block. But you try to close it *outside* that `else` block, meaning that `$stmt` might never be set before you try to close it.

## The Immediate Fix

Move your `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` inside the `else` statement where you set and use `$stmt`.

## The Real Fix

This code is what we call "spaghetti code." I don't say that to be rude; it's just the reality of what you have here. To avoid these kinds of problems in the future:

- Break your code into functions or classes.
- Avoid deep, complicated `if... elseif... else` structures. When you have as many `elseif`s as you do, something has gone wrong.
- Please learn how to properly format your code.
- Use an IDE.

You really should read through [PHP: The Right Way](https://phptherightway.com/) before you write any more code. It will save you a lot of heartburn.

Please note that you have some other problems in this code that I am not addressing here, such as injecting user input directly into URLs in `header("Location:...")` without any encoding or filtering. This could be used for, for example, malicious redirects or other nefarious activity. (You also likely have [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) problems on your other pages on your site.)